How to add timestamps in UTC
I want to add a time interval to MySQL timestamp in UTC. I tried to use TIMESTAMPADD(MICROSECOND, 10000000, UTC_TIMESTAMP(3)). My assumption was that the calculation will be in UTC but it's not the case. For example, if there is a DST change, it may generate invalid time (see the bug report).
Is there a way to take now in UTC and get time in UTC N seconds in the future?
It's part of a library, and unfortunately some of the users are running their DB servers in non-UTC timezones.

From the mysql bug report: If you want locale dependent arithmetic you e.g. can convert to unix time, do the arithmetic and then convert back. This should avoid the DST change bug.

?? MySQL performs all calculations assumng that all values provided are UTC zone ones. SELECT UTC_TIMESTAMP(3), TIMESTAMPADD(MICROSECOND, 10000000, UTC_TIMESTAMP(3)) always returns 2 timestamps whose difference is 10 second. And no error occures: fiddle If you receive some "Incorrect datetime value" then it may be springboot problem.

nb: updated to use 'INTERVAL' functionality.
is something along that shown below what you are after ?, if not, can you supply worked example(s) of what you'd be expecting.
SELECT NOW(), CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '-05:00'); select NOW() + INTERVAL 59 SECOND, CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00' ) + INTERVAL 59 SECOND;
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| NOW()               | CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '-05:00') |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 2024-09-03 07:32:08 | 2024-09-03 01:32:08                              |
+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NOW() + INTERVAL 59 SECOND | CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+00:00' ) + INTERVAL 59 SECOND |
+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2024-09-03 07:33:07        | 2024-09-03 06:33:07                                                    |
+----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



@Akina, tks, noted ! , i've updated to use INTERVAL.
